# What ARIA role to give for <li> elements that aren't options inside a menu?

Tags: menu, navigation, wai-aria

Given the following:

```
<ul role=menu>
    <li role=menuitem><a href="...">Go somewhere</a></li>
    <li><span>Some info</span></li>
    <li><span>More info</span></li>
    <li role=menuitem><span class="btn">Do something</span></li>
</ul>
```

What, if any, ARIA role should the *Some info* and *More info* `<li>`'s have?  Is there a good resource to authoritatively determine this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use HTML5:

The HTML5 spec lists which roles the [`li` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) can have:

> `listitem` role (default - do not set), `menuitem`, `menuitemcheckbox`, `menuitemradio`, `option`, `tab`, `treeitem` or `presentation`.

As you gave the `ul` element the [`menu` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#index-aria-menu) ("A type of widget that offers a list of choices to the user."), I think this list should only contain *choices* (i.e., `menuitem`, `menuitemcheckbox`, or `menuitemradio`). But it seems that your "Some info" and "More info" items do not represent `menu`-related choices, so they should probably not be part of that list (or be part of another `menuitem` in case they give additional information).

The roles `option` (for select lists), `tab` (for tab widgets), and `treeitem` (for trees) don’t seem to apply here. The default role `listitem` is for lists (`list`) or directories (`directory`).

If "Some info" and "More info" were merely for presentation, you could use the `presentation` role, but I guess that’s not the case here.